# "PROGRAM RECEIVED SIGNAL: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" with RNCryptManager.m

Tags: rncryptor

I am new to this encryption/decryption and I received following error

`"PROGRAM RECEIVED SIGNAL: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"` 
IN RNCryptManager.m  of DEcryptdata

```
NSData *key = [self AESKeyForPassword:password salt:salt];
```

When trying to encrypt/decrypt a string with password as "password" using RNCryptmanager.h amd .m files

```
NSData *en = [RNCryptmanager encryptedDataForData:data1 password:password1 iv:ivv salt:salt1 error:error];
values for iv and salt is a random data
NSData *ivv = [self randomData:32];
NSData *salt1 = [self randomdata:16];
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note that RNCryptManager has been superseded by [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor), which has more features and improved security.*

You should be receiving warnings about this code, which suggests you're ignoring warnings. You must never ignore warnings in ObjC.

The `iv`, `salt`, and `error` parameters are pass-by-reference. This method returns them; it doesn't take them. It should look like:

```
NSData *en = [RNCryptmanager encryptedDataForData:data1
                             password:password1 
                             iv:&ivv 
                             salt:&salt1
                             error:&error];
```

See [CPCryptController](https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/blob/master/ch15/CryptPic/CryptPic/CPCryptController.m) for an example.